# How to remove white border around Image in NextJs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I tried to remove white border on Image in NextJs and it doesn't help. Problem is actual only on mobile web browser.

[Image with white border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si6gG.jpg)

My code:

```
import Image from "next/image";

function Picture(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="relative flex cursor-pointer rounded-full bg-slate-200 dark:bg-slate-800" //  Tailwind for props worked unstable and I add style
        style={{
          width: props.size, 
          height: props.size,
          // border: "0!important",  doesn't work
          // border: 0,  doesn't work
          // margin: 0,  doesn't work
          // padding: 0,  doesn't work
        }}
      >
        <Image
          src={props.src}
          alt="image"
          fill
          sizes="100%"
          style={{
            objectFit: "cover",
            borderRadius: 100,
            // border: "0!important",  doesn't work
            // border: 0,  doesn't work
            // margin: 0,  doesn't work
            // padding: 0,  doesn't work
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export { Picture };
```

What can you recommend? Thanks

Comment: Are you using next 12 or 13?

Comment: I updated next to 13.0.0 version

Comment: Maybe [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#known-browser-bugs) is what you're experiencing?

Comment: Looks like solution, I add "priority: true" and it's working. The white border is gone. Thanks!

Comment: see this link: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21914